# How to build a simple Native WebRTC Android application that can do basic video call?

Tags: android, webrtc, libjingle

Recently I've been struggling a lot with WebRTC, I was able to build a very simple WebRTC web application based on the [WebRTC codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#0) which consists of a simple signaling server (basically step 8 in the codelab tutorial).

My next target is to build a **native Android application** that does the same thing which is to be able to **make video call with the web application** using the **same simple signaling server**. I am very new to WebRTC and I could not find any good tutorial or guide that allows me to build a simple native Android application.

I've searched for similar questions on Stackoverflow but most of them are outdated and do not provide useful answers that I need.
I'm hoping the Stackoverflow community who knows any good source or tutorial on how to build a simple and basic native WebRTC Android application can share with me their knowledge and information. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think you have to look into this article if you still needed it. [Android_Realtime_Communication_Using_WebRTC](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android_Realtime_Communication_Using_WebRTC)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you build the AppRTCMobile target in WebRTC (see https://webrtc.org/native-code/android for details on how to build etc) then deploy your own instance of AppRTC (https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc) if you wan to have full control over the signaling. Otherwise you can just use the one publicly available at https://appr.tc.

Comment: Now easier way is to add dependency (implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+'). Check out this [video chat project](https://github.com/duttaime/webrtcandroid).